# Does 'Hamiltonian' when describing a graph imply 'Hamiltonian Cycle'?

Tags: graph-theory

The question says to prove if the graph is Hamiltonian. Does this include a Hamiltonian path, or can I just prove that there isn't a Hamiltonian Cycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, hamiltonian implies a hamiltonian cycle. you can check out more on [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianGraph.html)